# How to grep two row values from a same json file and display them as columnwise side by side in another file?

Tags: json, awk, sed, grep

example_json_file:

```
{
        "href": "/users/115",
        "id": 115,
        "username": "test",
        "locked": false,
        "type": "local",
        "effective_groups": 
}
```

Assume we have a lot of these in a file. I want to grep the ID and username values from the json file and put them as comma-separated values side by side columns in another file?

I tried the following to grep

sed -E 's/},\s*{/},\n{/g' user_id_json.txt | grep '"id"'

It helps to grep individual field values. However, I need help in merging two field values like ID and USERNAME and put them in a separate file with comma separated values using a single command.

expected output

test,115

Comment: Welcome to SO, On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please post valid JSON.

Comment: You do not want to use `sed`. You **never** want to use regular expressions on JSON data, no matter the circumstances, it's always the wrong solution. In your case, you probably want to use `jq` (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: @Tomalak Is there any other way apart from jq?

Comment: Yes. Tons. But none of them involve regex.

Answer (score 1):

With valid JSON and `jq`:

```
jq -r '"\(.id),\(.username)"' file
```

Output:

```
115,test
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires Ed.  If we hypothetically assume that each JSON set has the same number of values/lines; which I know we probably shouldn't, then...

```
#!/bin/sh

cat >> edchop+.txt << EOF
1,8W temp
1,8d
wq
EOF

while [ $(wc -l example_json_file | cut -d' ' -f1) -gt 0 ]
do
  ed -s example_json_file < edchop+.txt
  name=$(sed -n '/username/p' temp | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ' | tr -d ',' | tr -d '\"')
  id=$(sed -n '/id/p' temp | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d ' ' | tr -d ',')
  echo -e "${name}","${id}" >> example_csvfile
done

rm -v ./edchop+.txt
rm -v ./temp
```